# Echoing a Product of Two Variables in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
    $sel_referrals1="SELECT SUM(amount) as da_sum FROM topup WHERE user_id IN(SELECT t1.referree
FROM referrals AS t1
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t2 ON t2.referrer = t1.referree
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t3 ON t3.referrer = t2.referree
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t4 ON t4.referrer = t3.referree
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t5 ON t5.referrer = t4.referree
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t6 ON t6.referrer = t5.referree
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t7 ON t7.referrer = t6.referree
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t8 ON t8.referrer = t7.referree
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t9 ON t9.referrer = t8.referree
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t10 ON t10.referrer = t9.referree
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t11 ON t11.referrer = t10.referree
WHERE t1.referrer = '{$_SESSION['user']}')
AND YEAR(date_time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
AND MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())";


    $selected1=mysqli_query($conn,$sel_referrals1);
    $sel_level1_array=mysqli_fetch_row($selected1);
    $level1=number_format($sel_level1_array[0],2);
```

`$level1` evaluates as **1260.00**.I have another variable `$rate1` which is set as follows: `$rate1=0.02`.I need to multiply `$level1` with `$rate1`. But, when code executes the   multiplication of `$level1 * $rate1`, the result yields **0.02**.

My expected result is **25.20**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This would work exactly as expected. There must be something you are not showing us.

Answer (score 1):

The data type of the $level1 is String in 3 operation (which will be converted into integer with value equal to 1).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you declared `$level1` with `number_format(1260,2)` value!
That its `echo $level1."<br>";` gives you 1,260.00!
You should declare it plain number!

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine.

try this:

```
<?php
 $rate1=0.02;
 $level1=1260;
 echo "Level1 = ".$level1.'<br>';
 echo "Rate1 = ".$rate1.'<br>';
 echo "Format Number using variables = ".number_format($level1 * $rate1,2).'<br>';
 echo "Format Number using numbers = ".number_format(1260 * 0.02,2);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, this particular snippet is but the OP indicates that the code that assigns a value to $level1 is as follows: `$level1=number_format($sel_level1_array[0],2);` which by default means a string value with a comma separator for the thousands.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from this statement in the OP's updated code:

```
$level1 = number_format( $sel_level1_array[0], 2 );
```

By itself, the statement is fine.  The difficulty is that next $level1 is multiplied by $rate1, producing a seemingly bizarre result of 0.02. It does make sense once you understand the way PHP's parser behaves.

By default, when number_format() bears only two parameters, it returns a numeric string which includes a comma as a thousands-separator.  So, the value assigned to $level1 is actually "1,260.00", which the world beyond PHPland recognizes as essentially the same as **1260.00**. The parser, however, disagrees as you may observe in the following example replicating this issue:

```
<?php

$rate1 = 0.02;
$level1 = number_format(1260,2);

var_dump($rate1 * $level1);  // 0.02
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/tA0k6)

If you set error_reporting() on, shockingly, the code doesn't even emit a notice with respect to the last statement -- unless one is using PHP 7.1+ (see [here](https://3v4l.org/NoUOV#output)) in which case it raises this error message:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered ...

The reason for this message owes to the comma that number_format() inserted into the numeric string.  Once the parser encounters that non-numeric character, after handling the first digit "1", it ceases to further process the string, causing it to prematurely evaluate as the integer one. Thus, to ensure an accurate and *expected* result, numeric strings should not contain a comma when serving as operands.

You may avoid this PHP "gotcha" by initially specifing that number_format() should exclude a thousands-separator, as follows:

```
<?php

$level1 = number_format(1260,2,'.','');
```

Subsequently, $rate1 multiplied by $level1 produces the expected result of 25.20; see [here](https://3v4l.org/KAXUV#output).

Alternatively, one may simplify the code and only apply number_format() to the final result; see [demo](https://3v4l.org/tQ7ph)